# How to affect other elements when one element is hovered in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have the following structure:

```html
<div>
   <div>
      DIV_1
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>
      DIV_2
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to change the width of **DIV_1** when **DIV_2** is hovered over. I've seen many [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047940/how-to-change-the-style-of-one-element-when-i-hover-another-element-reactjs) that involve setting a state and using `onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave` but that solution doesn't work well for my project.

I've seen how to solve this [using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered) and was wondering how I can do the same thing with JSX styling?

*Note: DIV_1 and DIV_2 do not share a direct parent. I need to be able to access either the parent of DIV_2 or DIV_2 itself from DIV_1.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "previous sibling" selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

Comment: That duplicate has direct answers with examples to what you're trying to do.

Comment: It helps explain a part of it, although there, all examples seem to have had the same parent. unless I missed one? here the actual divs are each in their own respective parent

Comment: There is no such a thing as "no-parent" element in html. Your divs do have a parent, even if it be the body tag.

Comment: Sorry. I meant no shared direct parent. I now edited the question to make that more clear.